# in "Crm dynamics 365 on premise" how to integrate the vignettes "Power bi" in dashboard?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi, dashboard, dynamics-crm-365

It have an option in "CRM Dynamics 365 on-premise" but I can't use it.
And I think it's strange to make an option if you can't use it.

[image: screenshot of the settings of CRM Dynamics]

I have an account on Power BI.
Power BI Desktop is connected to CRM with OData and I created a report.
Then I created a dashboard on the Power Bi service.

But the option to create a power bi dashboard or insert Power BI vigettes doesn't appear in the CRM Dynamics 365 on-premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn708055.aspx#PBI_op) for on-premise implementation is good starting point. If you face any issues there are lot of posts in internet.

Since you already enabled the System settings, go ahead & [add your Power BI visualizations in CRM dashboard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/add-or-edit-power-bi-visualizations-on-your-dashboard.aspx)

> You cannot add Power BI visualizations to system dashboards.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I didn't understand that I had need IFD to connect the CRM to Internet.